# Answer becomes Community Wiki?

Tags: discussion, support, community-wiki

I've just spent several hours researching and crafting an answer to

[Did journalist Amber Lyon claim that the US Government paid CNN to control content?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/15809/does-cnn-let-government-financial-sponsorship-dictate-content)

I've spent a great deal of time learning about the person in question and following several different sources to try and find the truth. (My answer is here: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/15828/1835) Unfortunately it seems the question has become a "Community Wiki" because I edited it 10 times over the course of my research.

This has taken me a great deal of time, so you can imagine I'm a bit sad to hear that I won't be getting any Reputation for it :( Is there anything I can do?

Comment: had same thing here http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/14856/was-the-2010-polish-presidential-tu-154-plane-crash-set-up/14866#14866

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You flagged it for mod attention. That was the right thing to do. Fixed.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you!

Comment: It has happened for me here too: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4409/do-women-prefer-taller-men/15589#15589. I spend time to add enough sources to my answer but it has been a wiki one! :)(

Comment: @PersianCat: As above; next time please flag it.